# Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object using Worklight 6.1.0?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I have WSDL stored on my local machine provided by Client, since its Sensitive data to publish in public i am posting modified version of it below.

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://www.Client.in/StoreLocator" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://www.Client.in/StoreLocator">
<wsdl:types>
<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.Client.in/StoreLocator">
<s:element name="GetClientStore">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="fromLongitude" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="fromLatitude" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="GetClientStoreResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetClientStoreResult" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="AuthsoapHead" type="tns:AuthsoapHead"/>
<s:complexType name="AuthsoapHead">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="FirstKey" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SecondKey" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
<s:anyAttribute/>
</s:complexType>
</s:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="GetClientStoreSoapIn">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetClientStore"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetClientStoreSoapOut">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetClientStoreResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetClientStoreAuthsoapHead">
<wsdl:part name="AuthsoapHead" element="tns:AuthsoapHead"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="NearestStoreSoap">
<wsdl:operation name="GetClientStore">
<wsdl:input message="tns:GetClientStoreSoapIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:GetClientStoreSoapOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="NearestStoreSoap" type="tns:NearestStoreSoap">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="GetClientStore">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://www.Client.in/StoreLocator/GetClientStore" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
<soap:header message="tns:GetClientStoreAuthsoapHead" part="AuthsoapHead" use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="NearestStoreSoap12" type="tns:NearestStoreSoap">
<soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="GetClientStore">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.Client.in/StoreLocator/GetClientStore" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
<soap12:header message="tns:GetClientStoreAuthsoapHead" part="AuthsoapHead" use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="NearestStore">
<wsdl:port name="NearestStoreSoap" binding="tns:NearestStoreSoap">
<soap:address location="https://www.Client.in/StoreLocator/neareststore.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="NearestStoreSoap12" binding="tns:NearestStoreSoap12">
<soap12:address location="https://www.Client.in/StoreLocator/neareststore.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

I am using Worklight Back-end Service to get results from this SOAP.
Find below the Store Locator Service URL to fetch the nearest stores based on latitude(fromLatitude) and longitude(fromLongitude) i.e. https://www.Client.in/StoreLocator/neareststore.asmx and Also look the test keys for Client Store Locator Service URL(Pass values in Request header) i.e. FirstKey:FTG8F535DFGDFGER8GFDGG4FG8DGS, SecondKey:password.

---------------------------------SoapAdapter1-impl.js--------------------------------------

```
function NearestStore_GetClientStore(params, headers){
    var soapEnvNS;

    soapEnvNS = 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope';
    var request = buildBody(params, 'xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:tns="http://www.Client.in/StoreLocator" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" ', soapEnvNS);
    return invokeWebService(request, headers);
}
function invokeWebService(body, headers){
    var input = {
        method : 'post',
        returnedContentType : 'xml',
        path : '/StoreLocator/neareststore.asmx',
        body: {
            content : body.toString(),
            contentType : 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
        }
    };

    //Adding custom HTTP headers if they were provided as parameter to the procedure call 
    headers && (input['headers'] = headers);

    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}
```

Now, i am directly Invoking Procedure from eclipse with below detail:

```
{
           "GetClientStore": {
                  "fromLatitude": "18.9750",
                  "fromLongitude": "72.8258"
               }
            },{"soapAction": "http://www.Client.in/StoreLocator/GetClientStore","FirstKey":"FTG8F535DFGDFGER8GFDGG4FG8DGS","SecondKey":"password"}
```

And i am getting error now as below:

```
{
   "Envelope": {
      "Body": {
         "Fault": {
            "Code": {
               "Value": "soap:Receiver"
            },
            "Detail": "",
            "Reason": {
               "Text": {
                  "CDATA": "Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
                  "lang": "en"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "soap": "http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2003\/05\/soap-envelope",
      "xsd": "http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2001\/XMLSchema",
      "xsi": "http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2001\/XMLSchema-instance"
   },
   "errors": [
   ],
   "info": [
   ],
   "isSuccessful": true,
   "responseHeaders": {
      "Cache-Control": "private",
      "Connection": "Keep-Alive",
      "Content-Length": "508",
      "Content-Type": "application\/soap+xml; charset=utf-8",
      "Date": "Wed, 09 Jul 2014 11:57:13 GMT",
      "X-Frame-Options": "SAMEORIGIN",
      "X-MS-InvokeApp": "1; RequireReadOnly"
   },
   "responseTime": 158,
   "statusCode": 500,
   "statusReason": "Internal Server Error",
   "totalTime": 159,
   "warnings": [
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i got Answer to my own Question. I had to develop a simple HTTP Adapter as below

```
function getLocation(latVar, longVar) {

    var request =
        <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:stor="http://www.client.in/StoreLocator">
            <soap:Header>
                <stor:AuthsoapHead>
                    <stor:FirstKey>FTG8F535DFGDFGER8GFDGG4FG8DGS</stor:FirstKey>
                    <stor:SecondKey>password</stor:SecondKey>
                </stor:AuthsoapHead>
            </soap:Header>
            <soap:Body>
                <stor:GetclientStore>
                    <stor:fromLongitude>{longVar}</stor:fromLongitude>
                    <stor:fromLatitude>{latVar}</stor:fromLatitude>
                </stor:GetclientStore>
            </soap:Body>
        </soap:Envelope>;

    var input = {
        method : 'post',
        returnedContentType : 'xml',
        path : '/StoreLocator/neareststore.asmx',
        body: {
            content: request.toString(),
            contentType: 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
        },
    };
    var result = WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
    var filteredData = result.Envelope.Body.GetclientStoreResponse;
    return filteredData;
}
```

Javascript will show red error mark for request but ignore and deploy and invoked it and i can see data coming as below:

```
{
       "GetclientStoreResult": 
       "<Response>
                <StatusCode>200<\/StatusCode>
                <StoresCount>3<\/StoresCount>
                <Stores>

        <StoreDetails>
            <StoreName>client Store<\/StoreName>
            <AddressLine1>Fatehabad Road<\/AddressLine1>
            <AddressLine2>Khasra No.-76, Mauja Rajpur, Near Amar Hotel, Fatehabad Road, Agra<\/AddressLine2>
            <City>Agra<\/City>
            <State>Uttar Pradesh<\/State>
            <countryCode>IN<\/countryCode>
            <Postalcode>282001<\/Postalcode>
            <MainPhone>09x 1x 0x71x0<\/MainPhone>
            <MobilePhone>09x 1x9 x97x9x<\/MobilePhone>
            <MobilePhone2><\/MobilePhone2>
            <HomePage>http:\/\/www.client.in<\/HomePage>
            <EMail>clientcare.upw@client.com<\/EMail>
            <Timings>1:10:30:19:30,2:10:30:19:30,3:10:30:19:30,4:10:30:19:30,5:10:30:19:30,6:10:30:19:30,7:10:30:19:30<\/Timings>
            <PaymentType><\/PaymentType>
            <Category>Mobile Service Provider Company<\/Category>
            <Description>Service & Sales Store for client<\/Description>
            <Latitude>27.164696<\/Latitude>
            <Longitude>78.038031<\/Longitude>
            <Distance>1.21778962564819<\/Distance>
        <\/StoreDetails>

        <StoreDetails>
            <StoreName>client Store<\/StoreName>
            <AddressLine1>VS Pratap Pura<\/AddressLine1>
            <AddressLine2>client Store G1 & G2 Ground floor Hotel Usha Kiran Complex Pratap Pura MG Road Agra<\/AddressLine2>
            <City>Agra<\/City>
            <State>Uttar Pradesh<\/State>
            <countryCode>IN<\/countryCode>
            <Postalcode>282001<\/Postalcode>
            <MainPhone>09x 19 x971x0<\/MainPhone>
            <MobilePhone>0x7 19 x7190<\/MobilePhone>
            <MobilePhone2><\/MobilePhone2>
            <HomePage>http:\/\/www.client.in<\/HomePage>
            <EMail>clientcare.upw@client.com<\/EMail>
            <Timings>1:10:30:19:30,2:10:30:19:30,3:10:30:19:30,4:10:30:19:30,5:10:30:19:30,6:10:30:19:30,7:10:30:19:30<\/Timings>
            <PaymentType><\/PaymentType>
            <Category>Mobile Service Provider Company<\/Category>
            <Description>Service & Sales Store for client<\/Description>
            <Latitude>27.15356<\/Latitude>
            <Longitude>78.007565<\/Longitude>
            <Distance>4.1715187443831<\/Distance>
        <\/StoreDetails>

        <StoreDetails>
            <StoreName>client Store<\/StoreName>
            <AddressLine1>Sanjay Place<\/AddressLine1>
            <AddressLine2>Shop No. G-1, Block No. 38\/4B, Sanjay Place, Agra<\/AddressLine2>
            <City>Agra<\/City>
            <State>Uttar Pradesh<\/State>
            <countryCode>IN<\/countryCode>
            <Postalcode>282002<\/Postalcode>
            <MainPhone>0x7 1x 097x90<\/MainPhone>
            <MobilePhone>0x7 19 0xx190<\/MobilePhone>
            <MobilePhone2><\/MobilePhone2>
            <HomePage>http:\/\/www.client.in<\/HomePage>
            <EMail>clientcare.upw@client.com<\/EMail>
            <Timings>1:10:30:19:30,2:10:30:19:30,3:10:30:19:30,4:10:30:19:30,5:10:30:19:30,6:10:30:19:30,7:10:30:19:30<\/Timings>
            <PaymentType><\/PaymentType>
            <Category>Mobile Service Provider Company<\/Category>
            <Description>Service & Sales Store for client<\/Description>
            <Latitude>27.198541<\/Latitude>
            <Longitude>78.006023<\/Longitude>
            <Distance>4.4289447148507<\/Distance>
        <\/StoreDetails>

        <\/Stores>
<\/Response>",


"isSuccessful": true,
   "xmlns": "http:\/\/www.client.in\/StoreLocator"
}
```